Why is the wallet address generated by ton4j library using 24 words different from the real address of the wallet created using ton blockchain apps?
public class App {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Pair key = Mnemonic.toKeyPair(Arrays.asList("artwork", "people", "where", "dolphin", "assume", "develop", "polar",
            "link", "company", "boil", "over", "shed", "clump", "fall", "seed", "flag", "private", "opinion",
            "budget", "follow", "install", "skill", "agent", "garbage")); //Key pair of public key and private key generated using 24 words for the wallet

            TonLibService tonLibService; // Instance of TonlibService Class
            tonLibService = new TonLibService(true, key.getSecretKey());// Instance of TonlibService Class with a parameter of testNet:true and the key generated above

 public TonLibService(Boolean isTestNet, byte[] adminWalletSecret) throws InterruptedException { 
        // Initialize TonLib with configuration files
        tonlib = Tonlib.builder().testnet(isTestNet)
                .pathToTonlibSharedLib("lib/tonlibjson.dll")
                .pathToGlobalConfig("lib/testnet-global.config.json")
                .verbosityLevel(VerbosityLevel.FATAL)
                .ignoreCache(false)
                .build();


        // Initialize Admin Wallet with secret key
        adminWallet = WalletV4R2.builder()
                .tonlib(tonlib)
                .keyPair(TweetNaclFast.Signature.keyPair_fromSeed(adminWalletSecret))
                .build();


        System.out.println("Admin Wallet Address:" + adminWallet.getAddress());

The address I got from here differs from the address from a tonkeeper app wallet that has the 24 words above as a secret key.
Why does it happen?

It is possible that you are using different versions of toncoin testnet. I have run your code and got the address "EQABkaXekKlGGtkzw0aB_KwGVtuQzSE-XLbXU5948s380s23" than i taped it in https://testnet.tonscan.org/address. And it tells: Contract Type
wallet v4 r2. Tape there your tonkeeper address and you will see.
I very interested in the subject can you write where you got this code, please. In the whole Internet your question is the only example of using ton4j.

Thanks for your answer. I've found out the reason of the error. The reason was the wrong config of the admin wallet.
// Initialize Admin Wallet with secret key
adminWallet = WalletV4R2.builder()
.tonlib(tonlib)
.keyPair(TweetNaclFast.Signature.keyPair_fromSeed(adminWalletSecret))
.wc(0)
.walletId(698983191)
.build();
Here, I added wc and walletId into the config and then I got to right address.
I hope to discuss more with you about ton blockchain.

Make sure to use the same version you created for use in tonkeeper

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
